# I am trying to assign the month wise leaves in an year to my database(sql server) but it fails. below is the code I have tried

Tags: sql-server

i trying to assign the month wise leaves in year in my database(sql server) but its fail below my trying code is there

```
select count(*)(SELECT DATEPART(yyyy,Date) AS OrderYear,
DATEPART(mm,Date) AS OrderMonth,
DATEPART(dd,Date) AS OrderDay
FROM Leaves
WHERE EmployeeID=37) FROM Leaves where OrderYear = '2016'
```

Comment: wheres it failing, whats the error? does the inner select statement work?

Comment: do you forger from clause ?? ......
select count(*) FROM (SELECT DATEPART(yyyy,Date) AS OrderYear,

Comment: assing the zeros in monthwise and also total value is zero

Answer (score 0):

This below code will do what you need to do. Just had to make some small changes to your above code:

1. you will need an inner query which will extract the date parts, which will then need to be selected.
2. An outer query will need to then select from the inner query and filter on the new date part field.

Here is how I would do it:

```
select 
    count(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        DATEPART(yyyy, Date) AS OrderYear,
        DATEPART(mm, Date) AS OrderMonth,
        DATEPART(dd, Date) AS OrderDay
    FROM 
        Leaves
    WHERE 
        EmployeeID = 37
) A
WHERE 
    OrderYear = '2016';
```

Comment: The above will return the dateparts and then you can use the OrderYear to filter on in the outer query. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You may looking for this :

```
;WITH CTE AS(

 SELECT 1 as MonthNumber 
 UNION ALL
 SELECT MonthNumber+1 AS MonthNumber
 FROM CTE
 WHERE MonthNumber<=12
)
SELECT MonthNumber,COUNT(*) 
FROM CTE
LEFT JOIN Leaves ON MONTH(DATE) = MonthNumber AND EmployeeID=37 AND YEAR(Date)=2016 
GROUP BY MonthNumber
```

Comment: how count it and set in terms of month wise brother

Comment: above script will give you month wise count of leave for those months which are present in Leave Table. what you looking for?

Comment: in date column yyyy/mm/dd  in those we fetched the months based on their year and employeeid and count it show in month column (like january upto december) and then they count it and display in total

Comment: sorry late reply,all ones come upto 13th column brother i dont know how to share my screen but its some not work brother